# Android which library should i use in non blocking socket programming

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets

I want to write and read data from multiple `sockets`.so i don't want to make it blocking `UI thread`.I know i can use `thread` for each connection.but before proceeding wanted to check if any good `3rd party library` is there which is useful in these kind of Application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check [Java NIO](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/index.html) or [Netty](https://bhardwajgaurav.wordpress.com/2014/02/23/netty-basics-for-beginners/) .Both handles these kind of operation very efficiently and gives you handlers where you can process your data and pass it to activities.

Comment: Netty seems to be good .thanks